# How to get files submitted from a form into a local folder using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to grab files put into the form into a folder in the same directory
all i have is the form and a the javascript for the file to be able to get selected

```
            <form>
              <div id="filejs" class="file is-info has-name">
                <label class="file-label">
                  <input class="file-input" type="file" name="stuff" />
                  <span class="file-cta">
                    <span class="file-icon">
                      <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="file-label"> </span>
                  </span>
                  <span class="file-name"> Upload file </span>
                  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit input" />
                </label>
              </div>
            </form>
         
    <script>
      const fileInput = document.querySelector("#filejs input[type=file]");
      fileInput.onchange = () => {
        if (fileInput.files.length > 0) {
          const fileName = document.querySelector("#filejs .file-name");
          fileName.textContent = fileInput.files[0].name;
        }
      };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get uploaded files from a form with client-side Javascript. You will require any backend technology for this job. You can use node.js as it is an asynchronous event-driven JavaScript runtime environment. There are many free packages available that can handle form files and form data like [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer), [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable), [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) etc.

Also, you can check out the PHP form handling method [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).